# Is it possible to create a color gradient background on cards that use a radial gradient?

Tags: html, css, styled-components, card

I want to make a card look like this

**expected**: the bg color is gradient (the green color behind img)
[image]

**actual:** in actual the bg color is not gradient, only accept one color(not gradient)

[image: result:]

the color that i want is gradient `linear-gradient(300deg, #6DBF67 1.06%, #A8DAA4 100%)` but in actual i cannot make gradient. Is it possible to make gradient? I need radial-gradient & filter for the side of card looks like ticket card.

my code:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.section-left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 64px;
  max-height: 53px !important;
  min-height: 53px !important;
  background: radial-gradient(8px at left, #0000 98%, #6dbf67) left;
  background-size: 100% 64px;
  background-position: top -70px left;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  /* padding: 10px 16px; */
}

.wrapper-img {
  width: 32px !important;
  height: 32px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
  background-color: white;
  /* padding: 5px; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.section-right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 53px;
  background: radial-gradient(8px at right, #0000 98%, #fff) right;
  background-size: 100% 55px;
  background-position: top -1px right;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  // box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0,0,0.12);
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  padding: 16px 12px;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div className="container">
  <div className="flex">
    <div className="section-left">
      <div className="wrapper-img">
        <img src="https://d3hi9gzi0oybee.cloudfront.net/assets/e-commerce/icons/ic-otten-point.svg" width="21px" height="21px" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="section-right">
      <div className="flex-sb">
        <h4 className="title">Title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my sandbox, please take a look [card-ticket](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/card-ticket-x6vy4s). Thankyou

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer. The difference between the expected result and the actual result is subtle, so you need to emphasise to us how they are different.

Comment: You can specify more than one background image (i.e. more than one gradient) in a `background-image` property.

Comment: @BrettDonald ohh i am sorry, I have updated the question, the difference is in the color of the bg (green bg), the color in the expected expectation is linear-gradient color (300deg, #6DBF67 1.06%, #A8DAA4 100%), but in the actual result the color is not gradient but only one color only

Comment: @Ry- ohh okay, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask to create the circular cut then you can easily apply your other gradient:

```css
.box {
  --r: 20px; /* radius of cut */

  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(var(--r) at var(--r),#0000 97%,#000) calc(-1*var(--r));
  
  background: linear-gradient(red,purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```